# A certain algorithm O(|E|log|E|) VS O(|E|log|V|) GRAPHS

Tags: graph, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, graph-theory

Let G = (V,E) be a graph.
Let |V| te number of nodes and |E| the number of edges.
A certain algorithm takes O(|E|log|E|) while another O(|E|log|V|).
Which is more efficient (preferable) in terms of complexity and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general graphs, the algorithm with runtime bound `O(|E| log |V|)` is preferrable (regarding asymptotic runtime complexity) because `|E| <= |V|^2|` holds. If `n` is the number of nodes, the runtime bound of the first algorithm can be expressed as

```
O(n^2 log n^2)
```

while the runtime bound of the second one can be expressed as

```
O(n^2 log n)
```

which is smaller.